# Is using EF Core include method inside a foreach can be a performance issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

These days I am working on a project, and this project depends on another project that will play the repository, my repository project based on `Generic Repository pattern`.
In my repository project I created a method that will get all data from a received entity and load data from selected entities in a received expression.

**My method:**

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions) where TEntity : class
{
    var result = new List<TEntity>();

    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        result = Context.Set<TEntity>().Include(expression).ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```

**The question:**

As you will notice in the above method I used `Include` method inside an iteration (`Foreach`), so my question is : is that using of `Include` inside `foreach` have a performance issue or any other problem ?

Comment: Considering you ignore all but the last expression's results, you have *correctness* problems which you need to resolve before you even consider performance problems.  Once your code works *then* you can consider its performance.  And when you get that far, measure the code to see if you have a performance problem, rather than asking strangers if your code performs well enough.

Comment: _you have correctness problems_, Can you provide me some examples ?

Comment: See the first half of my first sentence.  If you intend to ignore all but one of the expressions, only accept one, rather than accepting an list, running a query for all of them, and then throwing all but one of those results on the floor.

Comment: In the expressions I will send the related entities to load data from the main entity and all sent related entities so may sometimes I send one entity in `expressions` and sometimes I need to send many. And so sorry if I have a misunderstanding for your comment, please can you provide me a complete answer and really appreciate this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need this:

```cs
public List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions) where TEntity : class
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        query = query.Include(expression);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Anyway: https://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/